# "The method map(Function<? super User,? extends U>) in the type Optional<User> is not applicable for the arguments (MyUserDetails::new)"

Tags: spring, spring-boot

```
package com.sas.SpringSecurityJwt;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Function;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;



@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService
{
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        
         Optional<User> user=userRepository.findByUserName(username);
         user.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Not Found : "+username));
         
        
        return user.map(MyUserDetails::new).get(); 
        
    }

}
```

/*Am getting error in this line at map, its stating-> The method map(Function<? super User,? extends U>) in the type Optional is not applicable for the arguments (MyUserDetails::new)*/

---

```
package com.sas.SpringSecurity.jpa;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import com.sas.SpringSecurity.jpa.MyUserDetailsService ;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;

import com.sas.SpringSecurityJwt.model.User;


public class MyUserDetails  implements UserDetails
{
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean active;
    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    
    public MyUserDetails(User user) {
    this.username = user.getUsername();
    this.password=user.getPassword();
    this.active=user.isActive();
    this.authorities=Arrays.stream(user.getRoles().split(","))
            .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
    
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return authorities;
    }
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return  password;
    }
    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return username;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return active;
    }

    

}
```

Comment: does MyUserDetails extends UserDetails?

Comment: Please post your `MyUserDetails` code

Comment: yes it extends...Please find MyUserDetails code below

Answer (score 1):

In your `MyUserDetailsService` you have this import:

`import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;`

But what you really need is:

`import com.sas.SpringSecurityJwt.model.User;`

And as long as there is no compile error, I assume that your `UserRepository` uses wrong import too.

Change imports and your code should work.